# Alter Displayed Information in data-bound DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindingsource

I have a datagridview that is databound. One of the columns, which is shown below, is linked to a boolean value from an object. The method to retrieve the boolean value would be "curResultSet.Pass". Instead of saying "True" or "False" in a regular cell, I want that column to have a "Pass" icon or "Fail" icon depending on the value of "curResult.Pass".

I am fairly certain that my method of setting a .png to an Icon is wrong, but I can worry about that later. Right now, my biggest concern is I am not sure how to set a certain Icon in the DataGridViewImageViewColumn based on the value of a Boolean as shown in my code below.

```
DataGridViewImageColumn imgCol = new DataGridViewImageColumn(true);

foreach(RunResult curResult in curResultSet)
{
     bindingSource1.Add(curResult);
}

resultDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
resultDataGridView.DataSource = bindingSource1;

imgCol.Image = Image.FromFile(imageFilePath + "NG icon.png");
imgCol.Icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(imageFilePath + "OK icon.png");
imgCol.ValuesAreIcons = true;

resultDataGridView.Columns.Add(imgCol);
resultDataGridView.Columns[resultDataGridView.ColumnCount - 1].DataPropertyName = "Pass";
resultDataGridView.Columns[resultDataGridView.ColumnCount - 1].Name = "status";
```

Anyone have any idea how I can have my "OK icon.png" show when "curResultSet[].Pass == True" and have "NG icon.png" show when "curResultSet[].Pass == False"? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use a converter and bind the image source to the boolean value:
    public class BoolToUriConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        private const string filePath = "your path";

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool val = (bool)value ;
        string path = (val == true) ? $"{filePath}OK icon.png" : $"{filePath}NG icon.png";
        return new Uri(path);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And use it to bind your boolean column to the image column

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Collection1}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Field1" Binding="{Binding Field1}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Field2" Binding="{Binding Field2}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Field3" Binding="{Binding Field3}"></DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Field3, Converter={StaticResource boolToUriConverter}}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: This is the correct idea for a WPF `DataGrid`, but the OP is about a WinForm `DataGridView` - different animal completely.